# Center of $U_q(sl_3)$ and $U_q(sl_4)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups

In the book [a guide to quantum groups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521558840), page 285, the center of $U_q(g)$ is described in Theorem 9.1.6. The center of $U_q(sl_2)$ is computed explicitly in Example 9.1.7. I tried to compute the center of $U_q(sl_3)$ and $U_q(sl_4)$ using Theorem 9.1.6. But I didn't get explicit formulas as in the case of $U_q(sl_2)$. What are the explicit formulas for the elements in the centers of $U_q(sl_3)$ and $U_q(sl_4)$? Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't count on miracles here, since even in the classical case of complex Lie algebras it's tricky to write homogeneous generators of the center of the enveloping algebra of higher degree than the Casimir operator.   The rank one quantum group case is cautionary.    Maybe it's worth asking what you can expect to do with explicit formulas if you find them?    (Such formulas are largely avoided in the classical work of Harish-Chandra and others on central characters.)

Comment: @JimHumphreys: for the case of $gl_n$ (and hence $sl_n$) the formulas are quite straightforward, more or less $\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_k} e_{i_1i_2}e_{i_2i_3}\cdots e_{i_ki_1}$ for each $k=1,\ldots,n$, so one may hope to generalise them, I suppose.

Comment: @Vladimir: Yes, I can appreciate the combinatorial approach to $sl(n)$, but I'm also aware of the difficulty in working out centers for arbitrary Lie types.   Maybe there are ways to treat just $sl(3), sl(4)$ in isolation from the general case, which is where Chari-Pressley mostly aim their exposition.

Comment: @Jim Humphreys, thank you very much. I want to know the center of $U_q(sl_3)$ since I would like to study the Whittaker modules of $U_q(sl_3)$ (generalize the results in [the paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869305001882)).

Comment: @JimHumphreys concerning "it's tricky to write homogeneous generators of the center of the enveloping algebra of higher degree than the Casimir operator" I would say that currently it is more or less well-understood, how to write nice formulas for generators: there are Capelli determinants/permanents and even Okounkov's immanants which give linear basis in the center  - not only generators...

Comment: @Alexander: I was thinking of more general Lie types than type A, but I also don't know all of the possible literature here.

Comment: @JimHumphreys Capelli type expressions also work for all classical Lie algebras - that was done by Japanese people related to Umeda, more unified treatment via Yangians given by Molev Olashanky Nazarov (but it sometimes less explicit). In general that is related to many physicts works since similar expressions describe quantum commuting hamiltonians and physicists "like" explicit formulas ...